# Does Log4J2 have an equivalent of Log4J's Renderers?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, pojo

I'm working in a Java solution that is using log4j 2.11 as its logging framework. I'm also using a library that uses a particular POJO extremely frequently. I would like to be able to pass this object directly into a log statement `log.debug("POJO: %s", pojo)` but sadly this object does not implement toString and I am unable to modify the library code.

From what I've been able to tell, log4j 1.x had a solution to this via ObjectRenderer. You could implement ObjectRenderer and then in your log4j.properties file define a line such as
`log4j.renderer.com.library.Pojo=com.project.PojoRenderer` and then log4j would call your renderer to provide that string value.

According to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/compatibility.html however it seems this feature did not make it into log4j2. Is there an equivalent feature that I could use to log this directly without having to resort to a wrapper or helper method?

Comment: did you find solution for this? I too have some renderers. Unable to find a way to migrate them to log4j2.